# Credential provider in server 2008 R2

Tags: c++, windows, windows-authentication, credential-providers

I am newbie in credential providers.
I have made my provider taking SampleCredentialProvider as starting point. On some machines it worked.
Now I see that on WINDOWS Server 2008 R2 it doesn't work: it doesn't go further than instantiating credential provider.
In particular, I don't receive GetCredentialsCount call.
Could you please give me some hints on why it could happen?

Answer (score 1):

It could be for a number of reasons, but my guess is that you're either not registered in the right place (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers) or you didn't implement IUNKNOWN correctly.

I would try starting with [pGina](http://pgina.org).  It does most of the hard things for you.